# Chrome Extension Content Script Injection..background color of page not changing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Background page is not changing when I click on extension button.

Here are some examples that I tried, but none of them seem to work. Note: The newly injected scripts must be able to talk back and forth with the background-scripts.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "calender",
    "description": " pop up app demo",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon-64.png"
    },
    "background":{
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"],
    "icons" : {
      "64" : "icon-64.png",
      "128" : "icon-128.gif"
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browseAction.onClicked.addListener(
function(tab)
{
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.bgColor='yellow'"});
});
```

Comment: try `document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow'` instead

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow'"});
```

You can find a similar sample extension [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red.zip). It changes the background color of a page. I'm sure it will help you if you encounter more issues.